# How to secure Tomcat on port 80?

Tags: security, tomcat, web-applications

I have a doubt about how to configure Tomcat 5.0.30 in my web application to securize port 80.

My current configuration in server.xml file is:

```
<Connector port="8443" 
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="C:/Data/easyapIP/leaseplan/keystore/.keystore"
           keystorePass="aaassdddd" 
/>
```

And in the web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>listenPort_https</param-name>
    <param-value>8443</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The problem with this configuration is that our client can't access here anymore because 8443 port is block in their firewall.

It seems that 80 is the only port they are allow to use, so I was trying to do the require changes to securize this port.

The obvious changes were:

```
<Connector port="80" 
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="C:/Data/easyapIP/leaseplan/keystore/.keystore"
           keystorePass="aaassdddd" 
/>

<context-param>
    <param-name>listenPort_https</param-name>
    <param-value>80</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I can't get this to work, I receive an SSL error connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you uses https: // localhost/... ?

Comment: You receive *what* 'SSL error connection'?

Comment: have you tried withoud the :80 port?

Comment: This error: Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR):

Answer (score 2):

Standard port for HTTPS communication is 443 and it is very likely your users will be able to use that as well - just by hitting `https://` URLs with no port specified. It is very rare to block 443 on firewalls.

To test, change your server.xml to:

```
<Connector port="443" 
           ...
/>

<context-param>
    <param-name>listenPort_https</param-name>
    <param-value>443</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: We can't use that port because we already have another application listen on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a secure Tomcat 5.0.30: that version of Tomcat (5.0) has not been updated for something like 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was a firewall blocking port 80. We opened that port and no problem configurating port 80 as HTTPS in Tomcat.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your customer must access it through https://somewhere.com**:80**/something

Comment: put https:// before that. Can you verify that port is opened? check with netstat, also try to telnet to a port 80

Comment: Port 80 is open because if I configure an http connection (not https) it works. When I change to https, I receive an SSL connection error (error 107 mentionned above)

Comment: Sorry, I am already trying the access with the URL you wrote.

Comment: find "Use TLS 1.0" option in Chrome and check it. And try another browser too.

Comment: also try to change sslProtocol="TLS" to sslProtocol="TLSv1", not sure if that aging tomcat will be ok with it (btw, there is EOL announced for 5.5)